# Substitution that gives a division by $0$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, logarithms

When solving the following integral

$$ \int_{0}^{c}\frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{x^{2}}dx $$

(where c is a real number; it's a constant that really doesn't matter for the problem anyway), after doing integration by parts I got

$$ \left [-\frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{x} \right ]_{0}^{c}+\left [2\arctan(x)\right ]_{0}^{c}$$

which is

$$-\frac{\ln(1+c^{2})}{c} + \frac{\ln(1+0^{2})}{0} +2\arctan(c) \ .$$

But there's a problem. The expression

$$\frac{\ln(1)}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$$

is undefined. So what am I supposed to do in this cases?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I'm afraid that the primitive you found is wrong.

Comment: To be more precise, the fraction term is wrong.

Comment: According to my calculations your definite integral should be
$$ I= 2\arctan(c)-\frac{\log (c^2+1)}{c}.$$

Comment: Ofc it's wrong, I totally forgot the "ln" lol. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Choose $f'=1/x^2$ and $g=\log(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @vitamind thank you for the tip but my problem isn't the integration process itself, but the undefined division that it gets.

Comment: @Senna what happened to the $\frac{0}{0}$ term in your answer?

Comment: There is an underlying question that needs a response, although this question may not be relevant to this particular problem.  Suppose that : [1] $~F'(x) = f(x)~$ [2] $~F'(x)~$ is *undefined* at $(x=a)~$ [3] $~$ You have to evaluate $\int_a^b f(x)dx?~$ : **Answer**: $~~$ Compute the $~\lim_{c\to a^+}~$ (i.e. the limit as $c$ approaches $a$ from above), **if the limit exists**, of $\int_c^b f(x)dx.$

Comment: @user2661923 yep thanks, I realized that this is as a matter of fact an improper integral situation. My understanding of improper integrals as being exclusively $-\infty$ or $+\infty$ situations is now buried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is an improper integral (the integrand isn't defined at $0$), you need to take a limit.

Specifically, we want to know

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(1 + x^2)}{x}.$$

This is a simple application of l'Hôpital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(1 + x^2)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}{1} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{2x}{1+x^2} = 0.$$

---

In general, if $f(x)$ is undefined at $x = 0$ (maybe it approaches $\infty$, maybe the limit is finite but it's still of the form $\frac{0}{0}$) then

$$\int_0^c f(x) \;dx = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^c f(x) \;dx = \lim_{a \to 0^+} [F(c) - F(a)] = F(c) - \lim_{a \to 0^+} F(a).$$

Here $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

So when you write

$$ \left [-\frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{x} \right ]_{0}^{c} $$

that needs to be interpreted as

$$ \lim_{a \to 0^+} \left [-\frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{x} \right ]_{a}^{c} = -\frac{\ln(1+c^{2})}{c} + \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{x}. $$

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but, if it isn't asking too much, could you please frame your answer in the problem's context? I didn't get when you applied the limit, at what part exactly.

Comment: The context is stated in the first sentence: This is an improper integral. It is not defined *without* taking the limit.

Comment: Last question. Is the limit usually implicit when doing the calculations or is it good practice to write it explicitly?

Comment: @arpg You should write it explicitly. People who have practiced a lot of calculus will often omit writing some limits because they have seen certain limits like $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln x = 0$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^3e^{-x} = 0$ so many times that they can do that in their head. But keep in mind, mistakes happen when you calculate things in your head so the more you do in your head the more chance there is to make a mistake.